# C# Execution stops without error when trying to call a method

Tags: c#, execution

First of all I am stumped. I have a search-module for a CMS that runs fine on one site, but it won't run as it's supposed to on another site.

I have this code I call both with an Ajax call and simply when loading the search site:

```
private string GetSearchContent()
    {
        Query q = GetQuery();  

        //for each area, set it up, perform search and render result

        IArea products = new ProductArea(GetEcomExcludedGroupIDs(), GetEcomLanguage()).Search(q);

        IArea pages = new PageArea(GetAreaId())
            .Search(q);

        IArea news = new NewsArea(GetIncludedNewsCategoryIDs())
            .Search(q);            
        ....
    }
```

The important part here is the Search function. This is implemented in the classes, but for some reason the code won't be executed.

I have tried splitting the code up so I am sure that is where the error lies. The freaky part is that it does not throw any exceptions, but it just stops executing whenever I try to call the Search function. It doesn't even enter the function.

The Search function looks like this:

```
public override IArea Search(Query q)
    {
        log.Debug("Product search");
        ....
    }
```

The function it overrides is simply an abstract function on an interface that declares the function.

I have tried copying the function to the same class that are executing it with no luck, and I have tried accessing other functions on the classes, and that worked fine.

My question is then. What could cause this behavior? I have tried looking around but couldn't really find any others with the same problem. And as mentioned before, the exact same code is running smoothly on another site.

I really hope someone can help me get closer to a fix, or at least to understand the problem.

Comment: Can you post some more of your code?

Comment: How are you *sure* that it doesn't throw an exception? It could be throwing one of the exceptions that is automatically re-thrown after a `catch` block, which might create the impression of something that "just stops".

Comment: I am sure it doesn't throw an exception because there is no try-catch. In the Search method, the first thing I do is output to a log, and that code is not being executed.

Comment: Your argumentation seems a bit weird. You say, you are sure there is no exception being thrown, because there is no try-catch? How does a non-existing try-catch prevent exceptions from being thrown?

Comment: It may be a JIT-compilation error.  That would likely throw before it enterred the Search method.  Try putting a try/catch around the code inside GetSearchContent to see if you get any exceptions. FileNotFoundException and TypeConstructor...Exception are two possibilities

Comment: @BrandonZeider I would love to post all the code you need, but in this particular instance I don't see what more code would do. As explained in the text it doesn't execute the function no matter where it lies. But I have posted a small edit where I show the first line of the Search function, which is only a log, and that code is not executed.

Comment: @agent-j I have tried doing that, and no exception is thrown. Just to make sure that it wasn't some weird occurence where the log didn't work I tried putting in some code that I knew would throw and exception, and that exception was caught

Comment: The reason I asked for more code is because I suspected that you had overridden a method but that your override wasn't being called for some reason. It appears that may still be the case. If you can post both your base and concrete classes that would help.

Comment: @Daniel the argumentation was meant to provide an answer to the comment by JSBangs where he was talking about things in a catch block. I realise it might have been misinterpreted, but I meant that it didn't matter whether there was a catch block or not. No error is thrown or caught by the code.

Comment: @BrandonZeider I thought about that as well. I have tried making sure the class didn't inherit the method, and simply called it like it was only in that class like you would a normal public method, but it still gave the same result.

Comment: Is this a web application? When you throw an exception to test the logging of exceptions (and it "works" as the exception is logged), where is the exception caught and how is it caught? Do you have a global error handling mechanism in the game then?

Comment: @Tz_ Yes it is a web application. And the exception was caught in a simple try catch, so there is no global error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is unanswerable as written. You assert that the `Search` method never runs, and that the faulty line is this one:

```
IArea news = new NewsArea(GetIncludedNewsCategoryIDs()).Search(q);
```

There are a few different things that could be wrong outside of the `Search` method:

- The `NewsArea` constructor throws an exception
- The `GetIncludedNewsCategoryIDs` method throws an exception
- Either of the above could call into unmanaged code and generate a native Win32 exception, which under some circumstances will simple cause the process to terminate rather than ever returning to managed code.

You state that "there is no try-catch" -- all the more reason to disbelieve your assertion that the method just stops without throwing an exception. Try the following for diagnostic purposes:

```
try
{
    IArea news = new NewsArea(GetIncludedNewsCategoryIDs()).Search(q);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.Log("Caught in the act: " + e.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

If you've run this and *still* see that the execution stops without logging any exception, then we'll look at other possibilities.

Comment: I would also suggest logging something directly before and after the call, to ensure the code runs fine up to that point

Comment: Okay, I should have been more specific. I wrote "I have tried splitting the code up so I am sure that is where the error lies." And your answer and the comment is exactly what I meant I had done :)

Comment: I am gonna accept your answer. Turned out it was a dll I was missing. The weird part is that I tried the try-catch on the ProductArea, and it didn't catch an error, but when I removed the search calls from Product and PageArea and put it on the NewsArea, the exception was caught. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @Kaspar, glad to see you resolved your problem. I suggest for the future that you put in some sort of global exception handler to log these sorts of issues... it'll probably save you a lot of time the next time something starts mysteriously failing.